# Ionic Angular Tree View Nested Checkboxes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 3 page where I want to show this kind of data in a tree view.

```
{ id:0, parentid:null, name: 'folder1'}
{ id:1, parentid:0, name: 'folder2'}
{ id:2, parentid:null, name: 'folder3'}
{ id:3, parentid:2, name: 'folder4'}
```

I want to give to the user the option to upload a file and select multiple folders
to upload to.[image]

What is the best way to achieve this? I checked at recursive components but at the end I was not sure how to get the selected Folders.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone interested, I created it manually

https://github.com/missakation/IonicTreeView